# Lineplot with Seaborn and ci="sd" function

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, confidence-interval, errorbar

I'm trying to produce some snazzy charts in seaborn and need some help.

I have some stock data, consisting of 5 stocks. I'm basically trying to visually display how `Stock A` has performed in comparison to the others. To do this I am looking at cumulative returns, and have also calculated the average cumulative returns for the other 4 stocks. I have split this data up in to the following 2 `df`:

Stock A's data let's call `df`:

```
Date              Stock A               
2019-04-24 07:59  0.433366
2019-04-24 08:59  0.397984
2019-04-24 09:59  0.403971
2019-04-24 10:59  0.399131
2019-04-24 11:59  0.386641
2019-04-24 12:59  0.388572
2019-04-24 13:59  0.396266
2019-04-24 14:59  0.391609
2019-04-24 15:59  0.399412
2019-04-24 16:59  0.401715
```

And then Stocks B, C, D & E, PLUS the calculated average let's call `df2` (I can't print all 5 columns):

```
Date              Stock B   Stock C    Stock E   Average                                             
2019-04-24 07:59  0.273965  0.000982    0.409717  0.472029
2019-04-24 08:59  0.235606  -0.076309   0.345047  0.407299
2019-04-24 09:59  0.240826  -0.059274   0.346769  0.413197
2019-04-24 10:59  0.234849  -0.056013   0.338185  0.407962
2019-04-24 11:59  0.230158  -0.062947   0.331907  0.397927
2019-04-24 12:59  0.237573  -0.055506   0.334907  0.412206
2019-04-24 13:59  0.239994  -0.047875   0.334213  0.413846
2019-04-24 14:59  0.230461  -0.059781   0.312962  0.395924
2019-04-24 15:59  0.236968  -0.054398   0.320990  0.406967
2019-04-24 16:59  0.239918  -0.049522   0.328713  0.412818
```

What I am ultimately looking to do is chart all 5 stocks plus the average on one graph, that has a nice grey background and perhaps some grid lines etc (at the minute I can only chart with ugly white backgrounds), but I would like the line for `Stock A` and for `Average` to be slightly different and make use of seaborns standard deviation line plot.

I found this example code `sns.relplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", kind="line", ci="sd", data=fmri)` but when I tried to alter it to my needs I got error messages and couldn't get all the data to appear on the same chart.

Here is a near perfect example of what I'm aiming for, but I would like to include Stock B, C, D & E from `df2` and change the axis labeling of course.

Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers

[image]

Comment: what error messages did you get? and please show us what is the code you tried to use to adapt `sns.relplot` to your needs

Comment: Hi buddy, so I have since combined everything in to just `df` to simplify things. And just tried `sns.relplot(x="Date", y="Returns", kind="line", ci="sd", data=df)`, resulting in the following error message: `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Returns'`. I have clearly wrongly assumed x and y were labels, they of course seem not to be.

Comment: That is correct, `x` and `y` should be labels if you specify `data`. Are you sure your Column is named `"Returns"`? No typo in there?

Comment: Ah I see, no so each column is stock a/b/c/d/e etc, and they represent the cumulative returns, so I just assumed I could call the Y-axis 'Returns'. If I have to do each line on the chart as a separate line of code as you say in your answer then that would make a lot more sense, thanks mate. If I could be annoying and ask a couple more quick things. Firstly, the y-axis now says 'Average' when I just want it called 'Returns', even though there is no returns columns, is there just a label option? 2nd, my df has 1k data points of hourly data, and the chart tries to list every single hrly point...

Comment: ...on the X-axis, is there a way to reduce this? so just list every day or week, or worst case just no X-axis label at all? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce what you asked for:

```
sns.set() #This sets the style to the seaborn default (gray background with white grid on)
fig,ax = plt.subplots() #create your figure and ax objects
sns.lineplot('Date', 'Stock A', ci="sd", data=df,ax=ax) #plot lines
sns.lineplot('Date', 'Stock B', ci="sd", data=df2,ax=ax)
sns.lineplot('Date', 'Stock C', ci="sd", data=df2,ax=ax)
sns.lineplot('Date', 'Stock E', ci="sd", data=df2,ax=ax)
sns.lineplot('Date', 'Average', ci="sd", data=df2,ax=ax)
plt.xticks(rotation=-45) #makes ticks visible (a long date would be unreadable otherwise)
```

### EDIT

Answering OP questions from comments:

Transform your dates from strings to `datetime` objects, then `matplotlib` will take care of the ticks and `tickslabels`.
As they are right now they are interpreted as strings and they all get plotted.

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
```

Use the following line to change the `ylabel`

```
ax.set_ylabel('Returns')
```

Comment: Mate you're a legend, all works perfectly, thanks so much!